# How to make file manager confirm file deletion?

Tags: rhel, gnome, desktop

When I select a file in the file manager and press the delete key, the file is moved to trash right away. I'd like to have the file manager prompt me for confirmation before moving any files to the trash. How can I enable that?

I looked in the file manager preferences and the system settings, but I wasn't able to find a setting for this. Is there a hidden setting?

I'm using RHEL 8.5 with the default desktop environment (Gnome, I think).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126737/931617). Resuming: it cannot be done. You could search if other file managers do it. Thunar, Nemo, Caja, Dolphin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with `Nautilus` (which is what you are using) in RHEL / Gnome.

There is a preference for showing a context-menu warning, if deleting a file permanently (eg: using shift+delete), but there is no option for doing this when moving files to the trash.

Here are all of Nuatilus' preferences;

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.nautilus.preferences
search-filter-time-type
default-sort-order
recursive-search
open-folder-on-dnd-hover
default-sort-in-reverse-order
show-hidden-files
tabs-open-position
always-use-location-entry
show-image-thumbnails
search-view
thumbnail-limit
mouse-back-button
click-policy
mouse-forward-button
show-create-link
show-directory-item-counts
mouse-use-extra-buttons
*show-delete-permanently*
use-experimental-views
fts-enabled
default-folder-viewer
install-mime-activation
```

As i've highlighted (show-delete-permanently gsettings key), you can see there is an option to show a context menu for permanent deletion, but not generally for deleting/moving a file to trash... there isn't a hidden setting.

I would assume that gnome developers didn't see a need for it, as moving something to the trash can be undone. it's not permanent.